# How to properly update the existing div in Yii?

Tags: yii

I am using Yii framework and i want to update a div when click on a button.Div content updated successfully but its slider images are not updating.Here is my code view and controller.

https://gist.github.com/taleeb35/8da8a62141ef50cba794

This is my site when someone click on the update button new project and its images should be updated in div.

http://www.izons.com/portfolio/item/id/49

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: your tag is yii2 but your code is in yii1. its confusing.

Comment: Sorry my code is in yii1